# Shouldn't use getGraphics() on Jbutton.update, Why?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, custom-painting

I always do

```
Jbutton.setEnabled(false);
Jbutton.update(Jbutton.getGraphics());
```

when disabling a button, but someone told me that `Jbutton.update(Jbutton.getGraphics());` shouldn't be used, or at least not used that way. Why? is it not efficient? Is it incorrect? Should I change my method?

Comment: You should call `repaint()` instead. But normally, you don’t need to do anything, as `setEnabled(false)` will already trigger the repaint automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't use getGraphics() on Jbutton.update,

Actually it's wider than that. Programmers should never use `getGraphics` on any `JComponent` (or AWT `Component`) or the same for Swing (and AWT) windows.

> Why?

Because the painting methods are called by the API, whenever it feels the need to repaint (e.g. restoring a window from minimized, moving another window on top of or away from the window, bringing it to front ..).

So any call that uses `getGraphics` is 'transient'.

[ The correct way to do custom painting is mentioned in Holger's comment, but that wasn't the question. ]